# How to politely tell your senior that what they told is wrong?

Tags: sentence-construction, word-request, phrase-meaning, tense, phrase-usage

How to politely tell someone whatever they told is not correct according to me?
Is it okay to say "**let me know if I am wrong?**" after explaining them about that concept?

Comment: I can't help feeling Workplace SE or Interpersonal SE would suit the crux of this question better. (not that it doesn't necessarily fit here too)

Comment: The kinds of things which are most suitable depend quite a lot on context (what is your relationship to the person) and what kind of thing you are disagreeing with (money?  historical fact?  football superiority?  proper course of action for a business?)  Can I suggest you add a little more about your situation?

Comment: @jonathanjo foreg your senior gave  a mathematical problem to you and you came up with a solution but the solution is wrong according the senior. You try to explain him how your solution solution is correct and the solution given by your senior is incorrect.

Comment: @jonathanjo in this situation how to tell him in a polite way that  your solution is not correct and let me know even if you think I am wrong.

Comment: In that sort of situation, the polite way to do this is to ask him to explain why you are wrong and he is correct, because you do not understand. Then it is up to the other person to choose how they react - jumping into a conversation by saying that you are correct (however certain you are,) is likely to go badly.

Comment: In mathematics it is generally considered acceptable to suggest a proof that someone else's solution is incorrect, but it's still good to be tactful.  My suggestion would be "Can I show you my proof of why your solution isn't correct" ... and then afterwards show your solution.

Comment: @jonathanjo What if I want to write this in an email? I can't write "Can I show you my proof of why your solution isn't correct" in email. How to tell him via email that your solution is not correct .